# Scrollbar in browser missing

Tags: html, css

I got a problem in my webproject. The display of my pages in the browser is not working correctly.

On any of my pages the browser won't offer a scrollbar if the content expands over the size of the browser window. Tried with IE, Edge, Mozilla and Chrome. All the same.
My pages are built pretty similar. Here is the most basic page I have (just displays a pdf)

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

  <f:view locale="#{languageBean.locale}">
    <p:panel id="background" style="width:100%; height:100%;
    position:fixed; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0">
      <p:panelGrid id="grid" columns="1"  style="position:fixed;
      width:100%; top:0; left:0; right:0; text-align:center" styleClass="ui-noborder">

        <h:head>
            <ui:include src="/header.xhtml" />
        </h:head>

        <body>
            <h:form id="form">
                <object id="pdfDisplay" type="application/pdf"
                    data="file.pdf"
                    width="830px" height="800px">
                </object>
            </h:form>
        </body>

        <ui:include src="/bottom.xhtml" />
     </p:panelGrid>
  </p:panel>
 </f:view>
</html>
```

The two included pages are just p:panelGrid with a few p:commandButton in it. Which are included on top and bottom of each of my pages, same as in this one. Also already tried it only with the `<body>` tag inside the `<f:fiew>` tag and everything else removed form the page.

Can anyone explain to me why the browser won't display its scrollbar and how to make it work?

Comment: I think you have to add overflow:auto to your p:panel or p:panelGrid style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're putting all your content in a `position:fixed` element set to the viewport size, with no overflow.  So, yeah, it's not going to scroll, because you're specifically telling it not to.

```css
#background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0
}
```

```html
<div id="background">Lorem ipsum Dolores veniam incidunt sit et. Unde unde non minus deserunt reprehenderit voluptatem quia. Voluptas omnis officia iure voluptas. Est est molestiae mollitia incidunt aspernatur pariatur est dolorem. Veniam placeat veniam eveniet est qui ipsa. Corporis quam qui minus in ut.
Quo accusamus sit rerum alias quidem dolorum. Quidem illo et consequatur maiores officiis quibusdam dolorem voluptatem. Fugit occaecati eaque molestiae voluptatem non. Debitis numquam nihil eius. Et autem quis ipsam et debitis. Iure rerum optio nisi.
Placeat sed expedita et. Omnis facere blanditiis quis. Iure ut illum et quae esse exercitationem. Enim est quidem qui architecto facere vero nobis.
Enim quaerat quod tempora quo similique. Et qui voluptas aut corporis voluptatum. Tempora vel eligendi non harum porro sit libero. Reprehenderit quis praesentium voluptatem voluptatem. Excepturi non dolores autem.
Id eum labore eius sunt et doloremque. Fuga autem dolore quia. Dolor ab est vero in libero qui saepe sequi. Eos ad quae laborum mollitia quo natus. Nulla pariatur porro porro harum. Ipsa ratione neque ut quasi odit commodi omnis voluptatum.Lorem ipsum Dolores veniam incidunt sit et. Unde unde non minus deserunt reprehenderit voluptatem quia. Voluptas omnis officia iure voluptas. Est est molestiae mollitia incidunt aspernatur pariatur est dolorem. Veniam placeat veniam eveniet est qui ipsa. Corporis quam qui minus in ut.
Quo accusamus sit rerum alias quidem dolorum. Quidem illo et consequatur maiores officiis quibusdam dolorem voluptatem. Fugit occaecati eaque molestiae voluptatem non. Debitis numquam nihil eius. Et autem quis ipsam et debitis. Iure rerum optio nisi.
Placeat sed expedita et. Omnis facere blanditiis quis. Iure ut illum et quae esse exercitationem. Enim est quidem qui architecto facere vero nobis.
Enim quaerat quod tempora quo similique. Et qui voluptas aut corporis voluptatum. Tempora vel eligendi non harum porro sit libero. Reprehenderit quis praesentium voluptatem voluptatem. Excepturi non dolores autem.
Id eum labore eius sunt et doloremque. Fuga autem dolore quia. Dolor ab est vero in libero qui saepe sequi. Eos ad quae laborum mollitia quo natus. Nulla pariatur porro porro harum. Ipsa ratione neque ut quasi odit commodi omnis voluptatum.</div>
```

The simplest solution is just *stop doing that.* Remove all the CSS you've set on the #background element, so it can behave normally:

```html
<div id="background">Lorem ipsum Dolores veniam incidunt sit et. Unde unde non minus deserunt reprehenderit voluptatem quia. Voluptas omnis officia iure voluptas. Est est molestiae mollitia incidunt aspernatur pariatur est dolorem. Veniam placeat veniam eveniet est qui ipsa. Corporis quam qui minus in ut.
Quo accusamus sit rerum alias quidem dolorum. Quidem illo et consequatur maiores officiis quibusdam dolorem voluptatem. Fugit occaecati eaque molestiae voluptatem non. Debitis numquam nihil eius. Et autem quis ipsam et debitis. Iure rerum optio nisi.
Placeat sed expedita et. Omnis facere blanditiis quis. Iure ut illum et quae esse exercitationem. Enim est quidem qui architecto facere vero nobis.
Enim quaerat quod tempora quo similique. Et qui voluptas aut corporis voluptatum. Tempora vel eligendi non harum porro sit libero. Reprehenderit quis praesentium voluptatem voluptatem. Excepturi non dolores autem.
Id eum labore eius sunt et doloremque. Fuga autem dolore quia. Dolor ab est vero in libero qui saepe sequi. Eos ad quae laborum mollitia quo natus. Nulla pariatur porro porro harum. Ipsa ratione neque ut quasi odit commodi omnis voluptatum.Lorem ipsum Dolores veniam incidunt sit et. Unde unde non minus deserunt reprehenderit voluptatem quia. Voluptas omnis officia iure voluptas. Est est molestiae mollitia incidunt aspernatur pariatur est dolorem. Veniam placeat veniam eveniet est qui ipsa. Corporis quam qui minus in ut.
Quo accusamus sit rerum alias quidem dolorum. Quidem illo et consequatur maiores officiis quibusdam dolorem voluptatem. Fugit occaecati eaque molestiae voluptatem non. Debitis numquam nihil eius. Et autem quis ipsam et debitis. Iure rerum optio nisi.
Placeat sed expedita et. Omnis facere blanditiis quis. Iure ut illum et quae esse exercitationem. Enim est quidem qui architecto facere vero nobis.
Enim quaerat quod tempora quo similique. Et qui voluptas aut corporis voluptatum. Tempora vel eligendi non harum porro sit libero. Reprehenderit quis praesentium voluptatem voluptatem. Excepturi non dolores autem.
Id eum labore eius sunt et doloremque. Fuga autem dolore quia. Dolor ab est vero in libero qui saepe sequi. Eos ad quae laborum mollitia quo natus. Nulla pariatur porro porro harum. Ipsa ratione neque ut quasi odit commodi omnis voluptatum.</div>
```

The less simple solution is to add `overflow:scroll` or `auto` to that CSS.  This will work, but is unnecessary unless there's a good reason not shown in your sample for the `position:fixed` stuff to exist:

```css
#background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="background">Lorem ipsum Dolores veniam incidunt sit et. Unde unde non minus deserunt reprehenderit voluptatem quia. Voluptas omnis officia iure voluptas. Est est molestiae mollitia incidunt aspernatur pariatur est dolorem. Veniam placeat veniam eveniet est qui ipsa. Corporis quam qui minus in ut.
Quo accusamus sit rerum alias quidem dolorum. Quidem illo et consequatur maiores officiis quibusdam dolorem voluptatem. Fugit occaecati eaque molestiae voluptatem non. Debitis numquam nihil eius. Et autem quis ipsam et debitis. Iure rerum optio nisi.
Placeat sed expedita et. Omnis facere blanditiis quis. Iure ut illum et quae esse exercitationem. Enim est quidem qui architecto facere vero nobis.
Enim quaerat quod tempora quo similique. Et qui voluptas aut corporis voluptatum. Tempora vel eligendi non harum porro sit libero. Reprehenderit quis praesentium voluptatem voluptatem. Excepturi non dolores autem.
Id eum labore eius sunt et doloremque. Fuga autem dolore quia. Dolor ab est vero in libero qui saepe sequi. Eos ad quae laborum mollitia quo natus. Nulla pariatur porro porro harum. Ipsa ratione neque ut quasi odit commodi omnis voluptatum.Lorem ipsum Dolores veniam incidunt sit et. Unde unde non minus deserunt reprehenderit voluptatem quia. Voluptas omnis officia iure voluptas. Est est molestiae mollitia incidunt aspernatur pariatur est dolorem. Veniam placeat veniam eveniet est qui ipsa. Corporis quam qui minus in ut.
Quo accusamus sit rerum alias quidem dolorum. Quidem illo et consequatur maiores officiis quibusdam dolorem voluptatem. Fugit occaecati eaque molestiae voluptatem non. Debitis numquam nihil eius. Et autem quis ipsam et debitis. Iure rerum optio nisi.
Placeat sed expedita et. Omnis facere blanditiis quis. Iure ut illum et quae esse exercitationem. Enim est quidem qui architecto facere vero nobis.
Enim quaerat quod tempora quo similique. Et qui voluptas aut corporis voluptatum. Tempora vel eligendi non harum porro sit libero. Reprehenderit quis praesentium voluptatem voluptatem. Excepturi non dolores autem.
Id eum labore eius sunt et doloremque. Fuga autem dolore quia. Dolor ab est vero in libero qui saepe sequi. Eos ad quae laborum mollitia quo natus. Nulla pariatur porro porro harum. Ipsa ratione neque ut quasi odit commodi omnis voluptatum.</div>
```

(Same thing with your #grid; there's no apparent reason why you've set that to a fixed position either.  Trust the document flow! Don't override it until you actually need to!)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The problem was caused by what you mentioned. The reason why i was using the fixed position was so i could stretch a primefaces component over the whole background. I am using a primefaces theme (midnight) which seems to only effect components. So without a full-sized component in the background the empty bits of the page remain white, while the rest is adapted to the theme.